# Possible to rewrite \$a'b'c'd'\$ using NOT and NAND gates?

Tags: logic-gates, nand

Is it possible to rewrite  \$a'b'c'd'\$ using only NAND gates and NOT gates?

I tried rewriting it using DeMorgan's laws but got AND and OR gates which I cannot use. All help/input is appreciated.

I have 1 XOR gate available too in my project but I don't think that would be possible either.

Comment: Every boolean function can be written using only `NAND` gates (or `NOR`).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @EugeneSh. Any tips on how I could accomplish that?

Comment: Take a look at the "Related" list of the links on the right of this page.

Comment: if it helps, an OR gate with inverted *inputs* acts as a NAND gate and an AND gate with inverted inputs acts as a NOR gate. So you can always make OR gates from a NAND and two NOTs and you can make an AND/OR by putting a NOT in series with a NAND/NOR respectivley (you can also make a NOT with a NAND by tying both inputs together, same for NOR)